# Keeping the data of a variable between runs of code

Tags: python, list, save

For a school project I am making a hangman game in Python. Right now my code picks a word from a dictionary like so:

```
WordList = ["cat", "hat", "jump", "house", "orange", "brick", "horse", "word"]
word = WordList[random.randint(0, len(WordList) - 1)]
```

right now the list of words has to be set within the code before running it, but I added the ability to add words to the list while running it:

```
if command == "add":
    while True:
        print("type a word to add to the dictionary")
        print("type /b to go back to game")
        add = raw_input("word: ")

        if add != "/b":
            WordList = WordList + [add]

            print add, "added!"
        else:
            print("returning to game")
            break
```

however, once I exit the code, the added words are obviously not saved, so I would either have to manually add all the words to the list, or add a bunch of words to the list once the code starts every time. so I am wondering if there is a simple way that I can have the variable save after the code is finished, so that WordList will keep the added words next time the code starts. the program I use to write python is Jetbrains PyCharm, if that makes a difference. Apologies for any un-optimal code, I'm new to code.

Comment: `raw_input` has been renamed to `input` in `Python3`. see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3111/

Comment: As an addition, I'm not sure how complicated this questions answer is, and I'm not sure if it merits its own question, but is there a way to use the code to "edit itself"? like, if i wanted to make the add function physically change the actual code, in the "WordList = " line, so that rather than saving the variable, it changes the text in the actual code.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Simply pickle the data you want to keep persistent. Since your use case doesn't require very complex data storage, [pickling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) is a very good option. A small example:

```py
import pickle

word_list = ["cat", "hat", "jump", "house", "orange", "brick", "horse", "word"]

# do your thing here, like
word_list.append("monty")

# open a pickle file
filename = 'mypickle.pk'

with open(filename, 'wb') as fi:
    # dump your data into the file
    pickle.dump(word_list, fi)
```

Later when you need to use it again, just load it up:

```py
# load your data back to memory when you need it
with open(filename, 'rb') as fi:
    word_list = pickle.load(fi)
```

Ta-da! You have data persistence now. More reading [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html). A few important pointers:

1. Notice the `'b'` when I use `open()` to open a file. Pickles are commonly stored in a binary format, so you must open the file in a binary mode.
2. I used the `with` context manager. This ensures that a file is safely closed once all my work with the file is done.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for! you were a great help.

Comment: Can you remove the semi-colon after the append statement? Also, avoid using uppercase for names in python.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use persistent storage: write the words in a file when you add them and retrieve them from this file when the program starts.

Answer (score 1):

If you exit the code you stop the process. For this reason you lose all data. You have to add the words keeping the script alive. The suggestion is to use a server that processing all your calls (example: http://flask.pocoo.org/) or to use the python command **input** (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Input_and_Output).

But remember... if you stop the process you lose all data, it is normal.

Otherwise, before stopping your script, you have to save all the data into a file or database and load them when the script starts.