# How do I make my project remember a variable/list after it restarts?

Tags: python, list, memory

My project requires it to remember a user updated list. The problem is every time the python project restarts, the updated list resets with it. Here is an example:

```
list = [1, 2, 3]
list.append(4)
#the list is now [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Once I restart the project, the list reverts back to [1, 2, 3]. How do I fix this?

Comment: use a text file, that saves to your computer

Comment: Is there a way to save it to the project rather than a text file? Maybe a python package?

Comment: i'm not sure if there is a way to that, unless you want to use like an online database e.g. sql ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keeping the data of a variable between runs of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31891286/keeping-the-data-of-a-variable-between-runs-of-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save the variables, you can use a text file or a sqlite3 database which will be stored in your PC. If you like, you can use the `JSON` file also, which will be more easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the best but worth giving a try.

```
list1=[1, 2, 3]
list1.append(4)
with open(__file__,"r") as file:
    file1=file.readlines()
    x=globals()['list1']
    file1[0]="list1="+str(x)+str("\n")
with open(__file__,"r+") as file2:

    file2.write(''.join([str(y) for y in file1]))
```